# element is getting variable without declared

Tags: javascript

I am having a JavaScript code that is having a value in #message but i have not defined anywhere.
Does `$("#message").html(result);` is something inbuilt in Javascript?

I apologize if it is very basic and stupid question.

It is linked to my another question "
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41745209/save-javascript-value-when-converting-speech-to-text-via-webkitspeechrecognition#

Complete Code

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="Content/SpeechScript.js"></script>
    <title>Login Screen</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body >
    <div id="results">
        <span id="final_span" class="final"></span>
        <span id="interim_span" class="interim"></span>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">


        function Typer(callback) {
            speak('Welcome ,Please Speak your CPR Number');
            var srcText = 'WelcomeToDanske,PleaseSpeakyourCPR Numberwhat';
            var i = 0;
            debugger;
            var result = srcText[i];
            var interval = setInterval(function () {
                if (i == srcText.length - 1) {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    callback();
                    return;
                }
                i++;
                result += srcText[i].replace("\n", "<br />");


                $("#message").html(result);
                debugger;
                document.getElementById('user').innerHTML = result;
                //                var parent = document.getElementById('parentDiv');
                //                var text = document.createTextNode('the text');
                //                var child = document.getElementById('parent');
                //                child.parentNode.insertBefore(text, child);
                //                var div = document.getElementById('childDiv');

                //var parent = document.getElementById('parentDiv');
                //var sibling = document.getElementById('childDiv');
                ////var text = document.createTextNode('new text');
                //              //parent.insertBefore(result, sibling);




            },
            100);
            return true;


        }

        function playBGM() {
            startDictation(event);
        }

        Typer(function () {
            playBGM();
        });



        // say a message
        function speak(text, callback) {
            var u = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
            u.text = text;
            u.lang = 'en-US';

            u.onend = function () {
                if (callback) {
                    callback();
                }
            };

            u.onerror = function (e) {
                if (callback) {
                    callback(e);
                }
            };

            speechSynthesis.speak(u);
        }
    </script>


</div>
  <div id="clockDisplay">
    <span id="id1">Welcome:</span>
    <table width="100%" border="1"><tr><td width="50%">  Username : </td><td><div id="message"></div></td></tr></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `result` is a variable so it has to be defined...

Comment: search jQuery in Google

Comment: result is variable and I am getting value of result but what is #message? i have not declared it anywhere.

Comment: `#message` is the jQuery selector. It selects the element with `id="message"` and changes the html to whatever `result` contains.

Comment: Thanks,i have added complete code as you can see i have not defined #message anywhere.

Comment: Tell me if I'm wrong but didn't you believe that `$("#message").html(result)` put the html code of `#message` in `result`? The line `$("#message").html(result)` means get the DOM element with the `id=message` and change its html code by the content of `result`

Comment: Yes,I want to change the message element value by result

Answer (score 0):

*Fist off, remember to include jQuery as script in your html document or `$` will not be defined.*

`#message` Refers to an element in your html document with the tag of `id="message"`

To get an element in jQuery, *by id*, you use this syntax: `var Element = $("#ID");`

So, to make sure your code works, ensure that both there is an *element with the ID `message`*, and *a defined variable named `result`* containing the html text to put into your element.

Since you want to append to `<div id="clockDisplay"> <span id="user">Username :</span></div>`, why not change it to:

```
<div id="clockDisplay"> 
   <span id="user">Username :</span>
   <div id="message"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks But i could not see anywhere any element with name message

Comment: Exactly, you have to add in the element. Otherwise where would the client see the result?

Comment: I want the result in`<div id="clockDisplay">
    <span id="user">Username :</span>` but i am not able to get it.Instead of username or after username.

Comment: Either change the div's id to `message` or add a new div like so: `<div id="message"></div>`

Comment: Did That :
    `<table width="100%" border="1"><tr><td width="50%">  Username : </td><td><div id="message"></div></td></tr></table>` but everytime I am getting the value at top left corner.I want it after Username.Am i missing something else?

Comment: Relax for a second and think about what your code is doing. If you are appending to an element, but it's going to the wrong location, are you appending to the correct element? Do you need to add another element in a different location?

Comment: I was thinking,its simple.i am just changing the value of message element by result.but it is not coming at place where I have defined the element(i.e. in a table).Don`t know what mistake I did.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> $("#message").html(result); is something inbuilt in Javascript?
> ```

No.

`$` is a variable that is no part of the JavaScript spec, nor is it part of the common extensions to JS provided by browsers in webpages. It is commonly used by libraries such as PrototypeJS and jQuery. This particular case looks like jQuery, but you aren't including that library in your page.